# Add tab stop at: doesn't work in Word list

Tags: microsoft-word, list

Hello everybody and thanks in advance:
I'm trying to use the first line indent effect in a Word list, but I'm not getting it, although it looks correct in the preview. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the desired effect by adding another tab stop. To add it I had to disable Set left and first indent  with tabs and backspaces

[image]